# Bootstrap4 : Placing an image above a video

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, video

So I want to place a transparant logo on top of a video (that takes in all width and height of the main section). I'm using Bootstrap4 for this specific website, the video is responsive so I want the logo on top to be responsive as well. I did try the position absolute, position relative method without any result. So maybe someone can help me out on this one.

CODE:

HTML :

```
    <main>
  <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
      <source
        src="/artwork/Video/Final_Edit.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
      <img class="imgTransparant" src="artwork/Fotos/1x/logo_transparant.png" alt="transparante logo">
    </video>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS :

```
  video {
position: relative;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}

.imgTransparant {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your html structure and css little bit, hope it will work for you.

```css
.embed-responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    video {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .imgTransparant {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<main>
    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="/artwork/Video/Final_Edit.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <img class="imgTransparant" src="artwork/Fotos/1x/logo_transparant.png" alt="transparante logo">
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This didn't work neither, somehow, everytime i'm trying this method with pos-absolute & pos-relative, the browser makes a margin on top of the video & at the bottom of the video with the logo underneath the video even with z-index -1 on the video, but thanks for helping , appreciate it !